# How do I return all items in my data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, return-value, return-type

I'm trying to return all items inside my list so I can display it in a table using a different function and also reuse that same data extracted to make changes to it on another function.

The goal here is to extract data from an API that contains information about emulations/pods. With that data I'm generating pretty tables for the user to view and I'm also using it to make changes to it. Some of the changes are to enable/disable emulations and enable/disable devices existing inside each emulation.

Current function:

This current function works great but it needs refactoring, because I need to be able to re-use that same data inside **emulation_extraction** to print a table and also make changes to that data.

```py
    def get_emulation_id():
        """This will get_emulation data and based on the emulation name chosen
        by the user it will extract the data by using emulation id and format a
        new structure so it can build a table.
        """
        emulation_name = input(input_message(msg="Please ENTER Emulation name: "))
        emulation_found = False
        for data in get_emulation():
            if emulation_name in data["name"]:
                emulation_found = True
                emulation = tesuto.apis.Emulation.get(data["id"]).data
                emulation_extraction = []
                for device in emulation.devices:
                    # tesuto.console.output(device)
                    emulation_extraction.append(
                        {
                            "name": device["name"],
                            "model_name": device["model_name"],
                            "version_name": device["version_name"],
                            "enabled/disabled": device["is_enabled"],
                        }
                    )
                headers = ["name", "model_name", "version_name", "enabled/disabled"]
                pretty_table = get_pretty_table(headers, emulation_extraction)

                print("\nEmulation name: ", data["name"], "\n")
                print(pretty_table.get_string())

        if not emulation_found:
            print("\nInvalid emulation name, Try again\n")
            view_emulation_info()

        user_input = input(input_message())
```

When I try to do this it only returns a single element within my list rather than all my elements like it does when I'm manipulating the data inside **get_emulation_id** function:

```py
    def get_emulation_id():
        """This will get_emulation data and based on the emulation name chosen
        by the user it will extract the data by using emulation id and format a
        new structure so it can build a table.
        """
        emulation_name = input(input_message(msg="Please ENTER Emulation name: "))
        emulation_found = False
        for data in get_emulation():
            if emulation_name in data["name"]:
                emulation_found = True
                emulation = tesuto.apis.Emulation.get(data["id"]).data
                emulation_extraction = []
                for device in emulation.devices:
                    # tesuto.console.output(device)
                    emulation_extraction.append(
                        {
                            "name": device["name"],
                            "model_name": device["model_name"],
                            "version_name": device["version_name"],
                            "enabled/disabled": device["is_enabled"],
                        }
                    )

                print("\nEmulation name: ", data["name"], "\n")
               # print(print_device_table().get_string())
                print(json.dumps(emulation_extraction, indent=4))

                return emulation_extraction
```

Expected to see and what I see without the **return** statement:

```
Please ENTER Emulation name: pod41

Emulation name:  pod410 

[
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine1",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine2",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr1",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr2",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr3",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    ....omitted
]

Emulation name:  pod411 

[
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine1",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine2",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr1",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr2",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr3",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
   ....omitted
]

Emulation name:  pod412 

[
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine1",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine2",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr1",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr2",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr3",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "vmx1",
        "model_name": "MX",
        "version_name": "18.2R1.9",
        "enabled/disabled": false
   ....omitted
]

Emulation name:  pod413 

[
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine1",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine2",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr1",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr2",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr3",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    ....omitted
]
```

What I actually see with **return** statement:

```
Please ENTER Emulation name: pod41

Emulation name:  pod410 

[
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine1",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "nxos-spine2",
        "model_name": "NX-OSv",
        "version_name": "7.0.3.I7.4",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr1",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr2",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "csr3",
        "model_name": "CSR1000v",
        "version_name": "16.8.1",
        "enabled/disabled": false
    },
    ....omitted
]
```

Comment: The `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, so the loop never repeats. You need to put the data you want into a list, and return it when the loop is done.

Comment: or just change the return to a yield

Answer (score 0):

Put all the extracted results in a dictionary whose keys are the emulation names. Then return that dictionary at the end of the loop.

```
def get_emulation_id():
    """This will get_emulation data and based on the emulation name chosen
    by the user it will extract the data by using emulation id and format a
    new structure so it can build a table.
    """
    emulation_name = input(input_message(msg="Please ENTER Emulation name: "))
    extracted_emulations = {}
    for data in get_emulation():
        if emulation_name in data["name"]:
            emulation = tesuto.apis.Emulation.get(data["id"]).data
            emulation_extraction = [{
                    "name": device["name"],
                    "model_name": device["model_name"],
                    "version_name": device["version_name"],
                    "enabled/disabled": device["is_enabled"],
                } for device in emulation.devices]

            extracted_emulations[data["name"]] = emulation_extraction

    return extracted_emulations
```

Comment: This worked pretty good so far. This makes it way easier for me to display the pod name from the emulation separate from the pod details which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Make it a generator. Instead of a return, use a yield:

```py
def get_emulation_id():
        """This will get_emulation data and based on the emulation name chosen
        by the user it will extract the data by using emulation id and format a
        new structure so it can build a table.
        """
        emulation_name = input(input_message(msg="Please ENTER Emulation name: "))
        emulation_found = False
        for data in get_emulation():
            if emulation_name in data["name"]:
                emulation_found = True
                emulation = tesuto.apis.Emulation.get(data["id"]).data
                emulation_extraction = []
                for device in emulation.devices:
                    # tesuto.console.output(device)
                    yield {
                              "name": device["name"],
                              "model_name": device["model_name"],
                              "version_name": device["version_name"],
                              "enabled/disabled": device["is_enabled"],
                          }
```

This allows you call the function like

```py
result_list = [thing for thing in get_emulation_id()]
```

or iterate over it lazily like

```py
for result in get_emulation_id():
    # do something with result
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips. I was looking into generators.